# I need to rename a file in VBA, but getting "File Not Found" when it's clearly there

Tags: file, vba, rename

Help! I'm getting a `File Not Found` error when trying to rename a file with a variable. The variable is a `string`.

I can look at the variable and it's the exact filename that is there, but when I run the code, it says "not found"!

```
Dim filePath, fileName, absPath, newPath As String
filePath = "P:\Automated\"
fileName = MySite.GetResult
absPath = filePath & fileName
newPath = "P:\Automated\NEW.csv"

'The following is a rename from CuteFTP Pro COM Object:
'(Getting the same result from this and the below "Name".
'MySite.LocalRename "P:\Automated\" & fileName, "P:\Automated\NEW.csv"

Name absPath As newPath
```

Comment: Are there spaces in the name? What do you get with the filesystemobject?

Comment: Do you have permissions? Error messages are sometimes not very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about VBA, but normal languages require a '\' to be escaped.
So try "P:\\Automated\\" etc.

Comment: "normal"? Delphi is pretty normal. You probably mean "many languages", or "some languages"?

Comment: This is not the case with VBA, which is still moderately normal.